# Pivot table DAX measure for column average

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax

I have a list of rooms sitting in a single column of a data set. I have put this list into a pivot table with a count of the room numbers. I want to add a dax measure on the pivot table to work out the column average.

I only have read access to the raw data and also I need to keep the size down as the table has 1.5m lines. Running groupby and column averages in power query takes more time and space then I have.

As an example, the below is a list of rooms that have been put into a pivot table. I have then added a count of the rooms. How can I create a measure off a pivot table count where that count is not / can not be in the raw data. The average figures is 3.66 which would be expressed in each cell of the column average column.

| ROOMS | COUNT | COLUMN AVERAGE? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ROOM1 | 02 |  |
| ROOM2 | 05 |  |
| ROOM3 | 04 |  |

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your measure needs to transition context to ALL rooms, when dividing the count of rows, by the distinct rooms values:

```
=CALCULATE ( 
    DIVIDE ( 
        COUNTROWS ( Table1 ),
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[Rooms] ),
        BLANK()
    ),
    ALL ( Table1[Rooms] )
)
```